# highlight only one image

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a bunch of images displayed and I want to edit details of a certain image.

I want to select an image by highlighting it and then click the `edit` button.

It's already working but I am wondering, when I click the image for the first time, it won't be highlighted but for the second time, it will. 
Here's my code:

```
 mainApp.controller('employeeController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
     $http.get(BASE_URL+'Employee/getAllEmployees').success( function(response) {
                       $scope.employees = response

     });
     $scope.setActive=function(empID){
         $('img').click(function(){
           $('.selected').removeClass('selected');
           $(this).toggleClass('selected');
           $('#edit_eq').prop('disabled',false)

         });

     }
}]);
```

here's the HTML part:

```
 <button id="edit_eq" type="button" 
      class="btn btn-default" disabled><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Edit Employee
    </button>
 <div ng-controller="EmployeeController" class="row placeholders">
   <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 placeholder" ng-repeat="emp in employees | filter: name">
      <img src="<?php echo base_url();?>{{emp.image}}" style="height:150px;width:150px" ng-click="setActive(this)">
      <h4><a href="#viewEmp" data-toggle="modal">{{emp.lname}}, {{emp.fname}} {{emp.mname}}</a></h4>
      <span class="text-muted">{{emp.position}}</span>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: It's a bad practice to manipulate DOM directly inside angular, Use ng-class instead! or  for better control try to wrap everything up in a directive.

Comment: jsfiddle will be a help for all

Answer (score 0):

You function `setActive` is binding a new `click` `event` at every click you make on the `<img />`. In this way it will work only on the second click, because the first time it is binding again the `<img />`. Basically this is not the right approach for what you are trying to accomplish beacause the only binding you really need is the one in the **markup** (`ng-click="setActive(this)"`).

In fact, `ng-click` is already binding the `<img />` and in the `function` that it execute, you have to specify only what you want it to do, not binding it again and again.

Do something like this instead:

```
     $scope.setActive = function(empID) { //this get execute when <img /> gets clicked
       $('.selected').removeClass('selected');
       $(this).toggleClass('selected');
       $('#edit_eq').prop('disabled',false)
     };
```

Comment: When I did this, nothing is highlighted when clicked.

Comment: first of all, try to `console.log` something to see if the click is running and you are in the right scope